# configure file extensions in PyScripter

Tags: zpt, pyscripter

How do I configure the list of file extensions for syntax highlighting in PyScripter?

In particular I like to include Zope Page Template files (ZPT) with extension .pt to the list of HTML files to show proper syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it:

You need to modify the file filter for HTML files to include the .pt
extension in Tools > Options > IDE Options.